# Adding if-else condition as part of new machine pass is not getting preserved

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I have written a new pass that is run after Prologue/Epilogue Insertion & Frame Finalization pass. In the new pass, I am introducing a if-else condition using IRBuilder APIs to be added at the beginning of every function present in the file getting compiled. Using GDB, I can see in F.dump() (Function) that the if-else condition got added. But I don't see relevant machine level code in MF.dump() (MachineFunction). When I generate the final .ll using -S -emit-llvm clang options, I don't see the if-else condition. Is it getting removed somewhere later in the pipeline? If so, how to find that out?

GDB gave expected results but still the end result was not what I was expecting.

Comment: I've only glanced at that and long ago, and my memory may be faulty, but isn't the list of basic blocks in MachineFunction copied from the Function before the machine work, and the Function more or less ignored after that copying? Forget that, my memory *is* faulty, it's just a question of whether the faults are relevant. Check this hypothesis, though.